# Ending a sentence with a preposition

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, subordonnées

Consider the English:

> The chair which he sat on
>
> The chair on which he sat

Of course, the latter is grammatically correct English, yet the former has a much wider use in spoken and, in some cases, written English that it has become the most accepted.

However, in French, the only way I know of doing it is by writing an equivalent of the latter:

> La chaise sur laquelle je m'assieds

What I was wondering was if French had adopted a version of the former, or simply use it like the example above

I am guessing that the following is not correct but is my only idea at what a translation if the former could be

> La chaise laquelle je m'assieds sur

Merci!

Comment: Impossible de ne pas penser au Bourgeois Gentilhomme de Molière en lisant cette question! :)

Comment: Interesting question, but with a misleading title actually. The preposition must end a nominal group in your examples, in sentences like *The chair which he sat on ... [is broken/magic/whatever].* But the title says 'Ending a **sentence**...' When reading the title I thought about the sentence *Si vous n'avez pas d'argent, venez sans !*

Comment: Perhaps the most glaring examples of dangling (or at least superfluous) preposition "offenses" in English involve ending “Where” questions with an unnecessary “at” or “to”: “Where are you going [to]?” “Where are you [at]?” (“Between the “A” & the “T” is the standard pedantic answer to that question).  Although not involving prepositions, it’s my understanding that similar “offense” is taken by some (overly?) sensitive French grammarians when they encounter, especially in formal writing, certain questions ending with “comment” or “d'où”: “Tu t’appelles comment?”/“Tu viens d'où?”

Answer (score 2):

Voir [rubrique #6.3](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/rdp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=&page=../preposition), en effet ce type de syntaxe est un anglicisme à éviter.

Just watch out for the occasional (informal?) use of "pour", as in "C'est fait pour." meaning "it's deliberate."  Other examples of non-standard French are mentioned in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding#In_French) on prepositional stranding/ dangling prepositions.

Also, it is [somewhat debatable](http://www.newrepublic.com/article/113187/grumpy-grammarian-dangling-preposition-myth) that ending a sentence with a preposition in English is grammatically incorrect as it is a Germanic rather than a Latin language.

Answer (score 2):

En français le régime suit toujours la préposition. Il est parfois omis par ellipse (*c'est fait pour [ça]*),

Micromégas donne un lien qui qualifie la tournure d'anglicisme.  Même dans mon milieu — pourtant fortement influencé par l'anglais — elle est presque inusitée.  Pour moi, ce n'est pas le genre d'anglicisme courant mais combattu par les puristes, c'est le genre d'anglicisme qui marque l'apprenant anglophone, je ne suis même pas sûr qu'il soit courant chez les locuteurs non-natifs mais plus expérimentés. (La situation est peut-être différente au Canada, il y a des influences du Néerlandais que je n'ai plus entendues depuis que j'ai quitté la Belgique).

J'ai écris "presque" ci-dessus car il est un contexte où quelque chose comme *La chaise que je m'assieds sur* me semble possible. Dans le langage parlé, il est relativement commun de se lancer dans une phrase qu'on ne peut terminer grammaticalement par manque d'anticipation, et alors une reprise de la phrase avec une formulation plus grammaticale me semble courante.  Et l'usage de *que* plutôt que de *laquelle* est important dans mon exemple, *la chaise que* est un préfixe non seulement possible mais courant, *la chaise laquelle* n'est possible que dans des tournures plus recherchées, donc peu propice à un défaut d'anticipation).

Answer (score 2):

Une formulation québécoise équivalente existe bel et bien, mais comme le remarque Stéphane Gimenez, la formule n'est pas *La chaise que je m'assieds sur*, mais *La chaise que je m'assois **dessus***, car même en Québécois (en dehors du régime implicite, qui contrairement à ce qu'affirme Stéphane est attesté et complètement français, bien que parfois désigné comme un usage "adverbial"), les préposition *dans*, *sur* et *sous* sont remplacée dans de telles constructions par *dedans*, *dessus* et *dessous*.

Goosse discute en long et en large du régime implicite dans *Le Bon Usage*, 14e éd., §1040.

Comment: Je n'affirme rien du tout. Tu te trompes d'auteur :-)